# write text file from text files python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess, ipython

I have 3 output files containing x, y, z coordinates respectively

file1.txt (contains x only) | file2 (Y) | file3 (Z)

```
2.113
3.023
-7.234
...
```

and a parent pdb file which contains coordinates data. I want to extract only those lines from pdb file matching with x,y,z coordinates from file1,file2,file3.The pdb file lines are;

ATOM   1  O5'   G A  93     **-12.706  19.299   0.129**  1.00  0.00        O

The bold values would be my matching criteria to copy the whole line.

1- How I can merge the three output files to make a single file which can give me x,y,z coordinates in a line to work with my script.

final_file = [file1, file2, file3] ?

2- How I can extract points on matching criteria;

```
def read_convex_points(final_file,parent_pdb):
    with open("output.txt","w") as f1:
        with open(final_file) as f2:
            with open(parent_pdb) as f3:
                for line1 in f2:
                    for line2 in f3: 
                        if line1 in line2:
                            f1.write(line2)
    return               

final_file = "file1.txt"
parent_pdb = "original.pdb"
read_convex_points(final_file,parent_pdb)
```

I wrote function something like that but if condition is not working.

Comment: Your description is a little unclear. Are the coordinates in the separate files? Eg, the X coordinates in file1, Y coordinates in file2, Z coordinates in file3.

Comment: You have 2 questions here, they probably should be in separate posts. But anyway, if you're on Unix or Linux, the simplest way to join the 3 files into 1 is to use `paste`. It's easy enough to do in Python, as Peter's answer shows. Do you want to do the pasting in the same program that does the match testing? I think it might be a good idea to do it in a separate program, especially if you need to make multiple passes through the data.

Comment: yes, paste function works. i could not pass line1 in if statement. could you please give any clue?

Comment: Roughly how many sets of coordinates are in final_file and how many  sets of coordinates are in the PDB file? You can use a double `for` loop to do your search, but it's not very efficient if you have a lot of data. And at the end of the inner loop you need to rewind the file back to the start using `seek()`. Eg, `f3.seek(0)`.

Comment: final_file will have 62 while PDB has 1400. The 62 points were extracted from PDB file. I can run the program over 1400 in loop. It is giving me 1400 lines of single value. I guess I am not giving the right input which helps to copy the whole line.

Comment: Ok. In that case, first read the final_file data storing the coordinate tuples into a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set). Then loop over lines in the PDB, extracting the coords and see if they are present in the set. If you have problems doing that please ask a new question, with your new code in your new question.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found it helpful. I need to convert the output values as tuples. I hope it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to paste together multiple files in Python. It handles any number of input files, but like Peter's solution if the files have different numbers of lines it stops when the shortest file runs out of lines.

Fields in the output file are separated by the `delimiter` string, which is a space by default.

```
def paste(sources, dest, delimiter=' '):
    fsrc = [open(fname, 'r') for fname in sources]
    fdest = open(dest, 'w')
    for t in zip(*fsrc):
        outline = delimiter.join([line.strip() for line in t]) + '\n'
        fdest.write(outline)
    for f in fsrc:
        f.close()
    fdest.close()


paste(('file1', 'file2', 'file3'), 'final_file')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge files like this:

```
def merge(paths):
    with open(paths[0]) as f1, open(paths[1]) as f2, open(paths[2]) as f3:
        try:
            yield next(f1), next(f2), next(f3)
        except StopIteration:
            return

for x, y, z in merge((file1, file2, file3)):
    # check if matching
```

The caveat is this assumes files are of equal length, so it will stop the moment it encounters shortest file.  This is probably accetable.

Comment: Thank you for helping. it gave me error but paste function my linux make it simple. However I got my output.txt file empty after matching the coordinates. If I print line1 then it shows values but could not pass in following loop. Any guidance for this issue ? 
for line1 in f2:
                    for line2 in f3: 
                        if line1 in line2: